# C99: Custom implementations of non-standard functions

Tags: c, c99

In my project, I want to use a non-standard library function, which which may not be defined on certain systems. In my case, it is `strlcpy`.

From `man strcpy`:

```
Some systems (the BSDs, Solaris, and others) provide the following function:

    size_t strlcpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t size);

...
```

My system does not implement `strlcpy`, so I rolled my own. All is well, until compiling on a system that already has `strlcpy` defined: `error: conflicting types for strlcpy`.

My question: how can I implement a function that may cause naming conflicts down the road? Can I use some directive like `#ifdef some_macro(strlcpy)`, or am I simply left with renaming `strlcpy` to `my_strlcpy`?

Comment: This is provided as `strncpy` in other platforms if you don't care about the return value. Why not use that one instead.

Comment: If you're copying part of a string using `strncpy`, it wont include a NULL terminator, you have to set it yourself. `strlcpy` will put in the terminator for you. Just less lines IMO.

Comment: Well, if that is a problem then you'll need to roll out your own and use an `#ifndef _SOME_OS_HERE_` to suppress it for the environments where it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you need to include.

Example - the list of systems will be much longer I think

```
#if !defined(__FreeBSD__)
#include "mystring.h"
#endif
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. In my particular case, I needed to do `#ifndef __ANDROID_API__`